# Find the equation of tangent line to the given curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the equation of tangent line to $(x^2+y^2)^{3/2} = 2xy$ at the point $\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$

I just can't figure out how to take the derivative of this function!

Comment: HINT: square both sides and get that your curve has equation $$(x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implicit function theorem, which states that (in particular)

$$F(x,y)=0, \quad \text{and} \quad F_y(x,y) \neq 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{dy}{dx}(x,y)=-\frac{F_x(x,y)}{F_y(x,y)}.$$

First define

$$ F(x,y) \equiv (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}-2xy $$

then calculate

\begin{align}
F_x(x,y) &= \frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}2x-2y \\[2ex]
F_y(x,y) &= \frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}2y-2x 
\end{align}

and it follows that

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}(x,y)= -\frac{\frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}2x-2y}{\frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}2y-2x}.$$

Finally, substituting the desired coordinates we get

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)= -1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate implicitly and get $$\frac 32(x^2+y^2)^{\frac 12}(2x+2yy')=2y+2xy'$$
Substituting in the values, you get $$\frac 32(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}y')=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}y'\Rightarrow y'=-1$$